# Using laravel join query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm really getting confused with the join on laravel.

I got a `users` table and got a `students_subjects` table, in the `students_subjects` table I got a `subject_id` column and a `user_id` column, I'm trying to get the users list by the `user_id` at the `teachers_subjects` table with the same `subject_id` column at the students_subjects.

I've tried :

```
$user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$results = DB::table('users')
->join('students_subjects', 'students_subjects.subject_id', '=', 'teachers_subjects.subject_id')
->where('students_subjects.user_id', $user_id)
->get();
```

but I got some errors... would be great if someone can show me the way it should be done so I can understand how to do the joins work at laravel.

structures:

```
users table :
- id
- name
- last name

students_subjects :
- subject_id
- user_id (users->id)

teachers_subjects :
- subject_id
- teacher_id (users->id)
```

Comment: You need two different joins. One for students_subjects, and one for teachers_subjects. Right now, you're trying to join students_subjects on a table you haven't yet specified.

Comment: @aynber first thanks for the answer, can you maybe show me an example of doing it in the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a join for both tables:

```
$user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$results = DB::table('users')
->join('students_subjects', 'users.id', '=', 'students_subjects.user_id')
->join('teachers_subjects', 'students_subjects.subject_id', '=', 'teachers_subjects.subject_id')
->where('students_subjects.user_id', $user_id)
->get();
```

You may have to tweak this to get exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks that's I think I understand how it works now ty so much!

Comment: what if I wanna get the users with the same `teacher_id` at users->id

Comment: If you mean users -> students_subjects -> teachers_subjects -> users, then you'd just add a third join. **However**, I'd recommend aliasing the users table on the third join, because it would conflict with the first users. `->join('users AS teacher_user', 'teachers_subjects.user_id', '=', 'teacher_user.id')`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know to use laravel eloquent queries then you can execute raw queries using laravel if you are comfortable with it

```
$cards = DB::select("SELECT * FROM TABLE");
```

This way you can easily run your queries without any other RND